# replacement window flashing

Tags: flashing

We had replacement windows installed several years ago; they have no exterior nailing flanges but were installed via screws on the sides.  Now we are ready to replace the aging cedar siding with James Hardie Smart Siding (4 X 8 sheets).  When removing the old siding, we are left with windows that protrude about 1 7/8” from the sheathing.  We’ve filled the gaps on the sides, top, and bottom with appropriate expanding foam.  Now we are wondering what to do for flashing.  We will have ¾” X 3” cedar trim around the window.  Because there are no flanges, do we need to put metal flashing on top of the window frame and also on top of the cedar trim?  What about the sides and bottom?

Comment: Metal flashing won’t do any good as it is not part of the window. You could seal it with a adhesive flashing tape to seal up things better and you might consider insetting the window a little further having the windows protrude almost 2 “ sounds like a good place for a leak.

Comment: I thought you always put metal Z flashing/drip cap at the top of every window, flanged or not.

Comment: Hi, Cyd. Any chance you can provide some pictures so we can see exactly what you're dealing with?

Comment: Z flashing on top yes, but your question sounds like you want it all the way around.

Comment: I'll try to post a picture tomorrow.
Today I was given the advice to z flash above the window, then add the siding, caulk any gaps, then put the trim on top of the siding. Then caulk the trim. We were going to do trim first, then the siding (4 X 8 sheets that sort of mimic the old T-111). I guess we were thrown off by looking at local new construction where the trim went on first, then the horizontal siding.  I should also add that there is original tar paper in good condition and we plan to leave it and cover with Tyvek. Any potential problems with that?