# How do I properly flash a finless window on a wall repair?

Tags: repair, walls, windows

My house is 100 years old.  The windows are all double-hung vinyl windows retrofitted into sash window frames.  The sash windows had an angled sill, one piece from inside to outside.  The vinyl windows have no slope, no fins, nothing.

So I reframed and resheathed a wall that was rotting out, and I'm ready to flash and re-install the window.  I'm using this guide for the interaction between window, trim, flashing, and siding - however, I can't figure out what to do under the window without a flange.  Do I need a protruding wooden sill like the old windows had?  If so, how do I flash that, since it's a finished surface?

[image: LP Smartside window trim]

[image]

my question is similar to this unanswered one:  [replacement window flashing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171068/replacement-window-flashing)

The windows don't have an exterior sill either, so they can't protrude far from the opening.

I've watched some finless window installation videos on youtube, but they all seem to be european windows that are set far into the opening, and they don't cover how to trim them out.

This is where the weep holes are in relation to the bottom of the window:

[image]

More pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

proposed solution:

[image]

Comment: That looks like it might have been intended as an insert replacement window, which installs into an already flashed and finished window opening...

Comment: right, but when this house was built, flashing wasn't a thing.  and i'd rather not just cover everything with aluminum and caulk the ever-loving shit out of it as seems to be the style.  I just know that caulking always fails, and i'm concerned about water going between the window and the apron with no sill, and penetrating through the apron fastener holes.  maybe my concerns are unwarranted?

Comment: Yes, it needs a drip edge, a protruding wooden sill like the old windows had. It needs to be warped in trim coil anyway and I'm guessing you don't own a sheet metal break. So you reframed and resheathed with either a sill sticking out just like before, or you fake it out of trim coil. Or do it 100% right, which is both (a treated... and pitched!) sill, sill tape, and trim coil, not just paint which is why it rotted. Picture outside? Use Vulkem.

Comment: That (pictures +1). You have to put all that back. Either, ideally with wood behind it to wrap, or totally fake but that gets damaged easily. If that's the finished install then it's caulk time. **Vulkem**

Comment: you are correct; i do not own a sheet metal brake.  i added some more pictures.  i haven't cut out the window opening from the sheathing yet.

Comment: Follow the directions for sill tape window (entire) *rough opening*. Your only difference is you don't then tape the window flange, all you get is caulk, and you have to deal with the situation of making a sill because it's flangless. Then cased and wrapped because it doesn't come with integral j-channel. (maybe do something for a drip edge on the lower window while you got the sheet metal guy out.)

Comment: ... maybe go buy new windows ;) ... "something for a drip edge on the [TOP] of the lower window while"

Comment: @Mazura: That looks like an Answer...

Comment: ha, i was considering buying a new window just for this wall, but i'm going to have the same issue on all the other windows in some way or another as i replace the siding and trim.  frankly i hate the aluminum look.  

like the added image then?  please excuse the very rough sketch; angles exaggerated, i'm guessing i probably want about 5 degrees?